# Add a consecutive number at the end of a text in attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table

I want the first column (ID_1) here (see image) to have numbers at the end of the text.

For example:

Column 1: GI_01, GI_02, GI_03 and so on. I used concat expression but it doesn't work at all as you can see in this image.
[image: Attribute table_Column 1(ID_1)]
I also tried to export it to CSV to auto-adjust the column and imported it to QGIS (as points ofcourse).
When i tried to merge or join these column attribute table, it comes up with a NULL value or nothing at all.

Answer (score 3):

Try this expression
`'GI_' + lpad($id, 2, 0)`

[image]

Comment: Expression is not valid when i try this with field calculator. Can you elaborate more on how to try this expression?

Comment: `'GI_' || lpad($id, 2, 0)` or `'GI_' || right('0' || $id, 2)`

Answer (score 3):

Use @row_number with case:

```
concat('GI_', case when length(@row_number)<2 then '0' else '' end, @row_number-1)
```