# How to properly add consecutive numbers after text for ID in attribute table

Tags: table

So after trying this expression 'GI_' + lpad($id, 2, 0) I get this;
[image]

and I have about 12650 rows, and the id freezes in GI_10. I want the rows to start from GI_00 and end with GI_12650.

Comment: Please don't repost a Question [Add a consecutive number at the end of a text in attribute table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/434789/add-a-consecutive-number-at-the-end-of-a-text-in-attribute-table)